# How can I make an entire row have a border when a cell in the row receives focus?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus

I have a `JTable` with 4 columns.  Each column has it's own customized cell renderer.  When a cell receives the focus, it gets a border around it.  How can I make the entire row have a border and not just one cell?

Comment: If the cell renderers are customized, then can't you easily do this by checking for the row?

Comment: I don't want each cell to have a border since the sides of the cell would have a border.  I would like a border around the entire row when it has focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want each cell to have a border since the sides of the cell would have a border.

A Border doesn't need to occupy all for sides of a component. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information. You can use a `MatteBorder` and specify which sides of the Border should be painted.

So you have two options:

1. Implement a custom renderer for each column of data in your table
2. Override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of `JTable` to set the Border at a row level so you don't need individual renderers. Check out [Table Row Renderering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for a working example that does this.

Comment: OK, I reviewed the web pages you suggested.  Thank you.

Comment: If I use 1. or 2., then I will need to draw the border cell by cell (with sides missing on most cells).  So doing it in one place with prepareRenderer will be my best option.